# Android MediaPlayer notification API 33 not working correctly

Tags: android, sdk, android-mediaplayer

Media Player notification for Android is working fine with All APIs except API 33.
when pressing play/pause button below error in log

```
 application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
```

noting that notification is included in manifest as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

other info:

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

Noting also that run time permission for post_notification is called but no use.
code as below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, PermissionNumber);
        }
    }
```

and permission is requested and granted, still mediaplayer buttons are not working.

Answer (score 0):

on API 33, you have to request Notification Permissions at [runtime](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)

Comment: media player control is showing in the notification , but button function is not working. It is not permission problem.

Comment: I'm also not seeing my action being added in anymore either. The notification shows up but the stop icon is not there